# Distribution of stopping time for biased random walk using martingales.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

Let $X_1,X_2,..,X_n,...,$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $P(X_i=1)=p$ and $P(X_i=-1)=q$, $q<p$. Given $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ with $S_0=0$, $a,b$ positive integers and $T=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,|\, S_n=-a\,\,\text{or}\,\,S_n=b\}$.

How can I compute $P(S_T=-a)$, $P(S_T=b)$, and $E(T)$ using the fact that $Z_n=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{S_n}$ and $Y_n=S_n-nE(X_1)$ are martingales under the usual filtration given by $\{X_n\}$?

I was thinking to apply the optional stopping theorem, but I am not sure how to apply it. If anyone could give some hint, I really appreciate it so much.

Comment: Show that $|Z_{t \wedge T}|$ is bounded (which follows since $|S_{t \wedge T}|$ is bounded). Of course, $\mathbb{E}[Z_0] = 1,$ and $S_T \in \{-a, b\},$ so applying optional stopping to $Z_t$ should give the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may apply the optional stopping theorem to the first problem, because $|Z_{n \land T}| \leq r < \infty$ for some $r$, and get:
$$1 = E(Z_0) = E(Z_T) = (q/p)^{-a} P(S_T = -a) + (q/p)^{b} P(S_T = b)$$

Using the fact that $P(S_T = b) = 1 - P(S_T = -a)$, we may rearrange to get: $$
\begin{align*}
P(S_T = b) &= \frac{1- (q/p)^{-a}}{(q/p)^b - (q/p)^{-a}}  \\
P(S_T = -a) &= \frac{(q/p)^b - 1}{(q/p)^b - (q/p)^{-a}}
\end{align*}$$

To see that the optional stopping theorem holds for $Y_n$, note that it has bounded increments and that you may stochastically bound $Y_n$ by a geometric random variable (e.g. $T \leq (a+b)G$ where $G \sim Geo(q^{a+b})$) to get that $E(T) < \infty$.

You may also apply the optional stopping theorem to $Y_n$ to get:
$$0 = E(Y_0) = E(Y_T) = E(S_T) - E(T)E(X_1)$$

So that $E(T) = E(S_T) / E(X_1)$, whose exact value you can now calculate from a previous question.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Would this answer change if Xi could take 3 values -1,0 ,1 with probability 1/2,1/4 and 1/4 respectively?

Comment: @codelearner Yes. Presumably, you'd need to use a different martingale to argue in this way.

Comment: Why is it true that $|Z_{n \wedge T}| \leq 1$? It is possible for $S_T$ to be negative, in which case $(q/p)^{S_T} > 1$.

Comment: @user111 You are right. The important thing to note is that $|Z_{n\land T}|$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am still a bit confused though. Why does the martingale being bounded for truncated stopping times imply that we can apply optional stopping theorem? It still doesn't seem to satisfy any of the conditions listed here, as the bound only applies to a single value of $n$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem

Comment: @user111 See condition (c) in your link.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Could you just clarify if $E\left(S_{T}\right) = -a * P\left(S_{T}=-a\right) + b * P\left(S_{T}=b\right)?$

Comment: @codelearner Yes, that is correct. You can compute that by using the probabilities derived in this post.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I was initially confused because condition (c) in my link seems to require that c holds for all values of $t$, here $n$. Your value of $r$ is depending on the choice of $n$. However, I see now that since $-a \leq S_T \leq b$, there is a value of $r$ that works for all $n$, in particular $(q/p)^{-a}$. Thanks!